# calling one python object from another

Tags: python-3.x, object

I have two different modules (files) where I store different objects.

The work flow is - call objects from different files and return the values from the database. If I call object from file_1 below, it returns required values from the database. However when I call object from file_1 in file_2, it returns 'None' even though input parameter is supplied.

file_1

```
class Database(object):

  database        = None
  host            = None
  port            = None

  
  def __init__(self, host=None, port=None):
    self.host=None
    self.port=None
    
    
  def client_(self):
    return MongoClient()


  def find_spefic_director(self, db=None, coll=None, directorId=None):
    '''If when a specific director id is supplied it returns director related information'''

    project={'_id': 0}
    
    filter={'directorid': directorId}
    print(directorId)

    if not directorId is None:

      result = self.client_()[db][coll].find(projection=project,
        filter=filter)

      return [i for i in result]
    else:
      return 'valid Id is required'




if __name__ == "__main__":
    Database()
```

file_2

```
class Graph(object):

  
  
  def __init__(self, host=None, port=None):
    self.host=None
    self.port=None
    self.directorId=None


  def minMaxDate(self, db=None, coll=None, directorId=None):

    dr= Database(self.host, self.port).find_spefic_director(self.directorId)
    drt=dr(directorId)

    
    

    return drt
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Graph()
```

Now I am trying to call Database() in file 2 for further processing in a different file

```
from file_1 import Database

from file_2 import Graph as gc

gc(directorId=340769.0).minMaxDate(db, coll='directory', directorId=340769.0)
```

when I run, it returns

```
None
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-2d56a89c0288> in <module>
----> 1 gc().minMaxDate(db, coll='crsp_na_wrds_company_director_names', directorId=340769.0)

~/graph_construct.py in minMaxDate(self, db, coll, directorId)
     25 
     26     dr= Database(self.host, self.port).find_spefic_director(self.directorId)
---> 27     drt=dr(directorId)
     28 
     29 

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What should be done to return the values stored in the database?

Comment: You're instantiating `Graph` without the `host` and `port` arguments. `gc(directorId=340769.0)`. Can you explain why or how you expect it to work?

Comment: I get the point, but with those two arguments I get different error.  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1818ce22cdc7> in <module>
----> 1 gc(host, port).minMaxDate(db, coll='crsp_na_wrds_company_director_names', directorId=340769.0)

TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given

Comment: Okay, it got resolved, so I were missing positional arguments here:def minMaxDate(self, db=None, coll=None, directorId=None):
    
    dr= Database(self.host, self.port).find_spefic_director(db, coll, directorId)
    print(dr)
   


    return dr    and called as  gc().minMaxDate(db, coll='crsp_na_wrds_company_director_names', directorId=340769.0)